# How can I create an XML when an invoice gets created in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, invoice

How can I create an XML when an **invoice** has been created. Whenever order invoice gets created, it creates in a particular folder automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things that you need to do is listed below:

1. You need to create a simple module that will look for event **sales_order_invoice_save_after**. This event is triggered when invoice is generated. You can check tutorials to understand event observer concept from [here](https://www.pierrefay.com/magento-training/event-observer.html) or you can quickly create your module using module creator from [here](https://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/)
2. After creating the module Go to the file named **Observer.php** inside **Model** folder of your module.
3. Now in that function of your **Observer.php** file use something like below to get the invoice id.

   ```
       $invoiceId = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getOrigData('entity_id');
       if(is_null($invoiceId )){
       // do your logic
       }
   ```

   And you can get your item info

   ```
     <?php
     foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item){
                   if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                       continue;
                   }   
           $name = $item->getName();
           $type = $item->getSku();
           $id = $item->getProductId();
           $qty = $item->getQty();

           }
   ```

Now you get all the invoice information and you can generate your xml from here.

I think above answer helps you. If it does please do accept and vote up the answer.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Its my pleasure!!